# can I repeatedly change my shipping address at paypal checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to build a service that orders products off the internet for other people. They pay me for their service and then I go about ordering that product with my paypal account and shipping it to their address.

The problem is that at paypal checkout adding and deleting a shipping address is a little painstaking and I'm sure if I change my shipping address 100 - 500 times in a year my account might be shut down for investigation.

I'm wondering if I can customize a checkout experience that allows me to fill in a new shipping address every time I checkout with out having to save/delete anything. It would make a much more streamlined experience for me.

This is not an illegal activity. Please keep any answers on topic. I'm not looking for feedback about my service at this time. Just an answer or direction on paypal options. Thanks.

Comment: Is this for use through eBay or just in general? Will affect my answer

Comment: just in general. I'm looking to customize my own checkout experience on someone else's website and not someones experience on my website just to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but, in theory, it might work. You could try a [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) call. So, my theory is that you would set your shipping address in the SEC call, log in and it would theoretically add the new shipping address to your account. You wouldn't need to complete the process, just start it. Lots of "if"s but worth a shot.